# dealing with dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I started with a date frame composed by day, a column called wap and a list of products.
For a given product, I calculated the results that are basically some operation in the column waps and saving in a new column. (Vide code above)

```
NEG_00_04_p =  waps_df1[waps_df1['produktname']=='NEG_00_04'] #one prodkt NEG_00_04
NEG_00_04_p = NEG_00_04_p.reset_index()
NEG_00_04_p1 = []
NEG_00_04_p['Diff'] = -NEG_00_04_p['wap'].diff(-1) 
NEG_00_04_p['Diff'].shift(+1).fillna(0)
NEG_00_04_p['Diff'] = NEG_00_04_p['NewColumn'].shift(+1).fillna(0)
NEG_00_04_p['Result'] = NEG_00_04_p['NewColumn'] + NEG_00_04_p['wap']
```

As a result, I obtained this:

```
index   datum_von   datum_bis produktname    wap   Diff
0       0  2017-10-10  2017-10-10   NEG_00_04   2.10   1.32
1      12  2017-10-11  2017-10-11   NEG_00_04   3.42  18.27
2      24  2017-10-12  2017-10-12   NEG_00_04  21.69  -4.92
3      36  2017-10-13  2017-10-13   NEG_00_04  16.77  -4.47
4      48  2017-10-14  2017-10-14   NEG_00_04  12.30   1.17
5      60  2017-10-15  2017-10-15   NEG_00_04  13.47  -4.18
6      72  2017-10-16  2017-10-16   NEG_00_04   9.29   1.40
7      84  2017-10-17  2017-10-17   NEG_00_04  10.69  -1.11
8      96  2017-10-18  2017-10-18   NEG_00_04   9.58  -1.62
```

Happens that in the initial date frame I have many products (12 in total) and many days which repeats for every product, such as:

```
datum_von produktname    wap
0    2017-10-10   NEG_00_04   2.10
1    2017-10-10   NEG_04_08   1.50
2    2017-10-10   NEG_08_12   0.50
3    2017-10-10   NEG_12_16   0.55
4    2017-10-10   NEG_16_20   0.52
5    2017-10-10   NEG_20_24   0.48
6    2017-10-10   POS_00_04   0.00
7    2017-10-10   POS_04_08   0.00
8    2017-10-10   POS_08_12   0.42
9    2017-10-10   POS_12_16   0.00
10   2017-10-10   POS_16_20   1.04
11   2017-10-10   POS_20_24   0.00
12   2017-10-11   NEG_00_04   3.42
13   2017-10-11   NEG_04_08   4.91
14   2017-10-11   NEG_08_12   0.31
15   2017-10-11   NEG_12_16   0.34
16   2017-10-11   NEG_16_20   0.45
17   2017-10-11   NEG_20_24   0.50
18   2017-10-11   POS_00_04   0.00
19   2017-10-11   POS_04_08   0.00
20   2017-10-11   POS_08_12   0.12
21   2017-10-11   POS_12_16   0.00
22   2017-10-11   POS_16_20   1.28
23   2017-10-11   POS_20_24   0.00
24   2017-10-12   NEG_00_04  21.69
25   2017-10-12   NEG_04_08  15.36
26   2017-10-12   NEG_08_12   0.87
27   2017-10-12   NEG_12_16   1.42
28   2017-10-12   NEG_16_20   0.76
29   2017-10-12   NEG_20_24   0.65
..          ...         ...    ...
150  2017-10-22   POS_00_04   0.00
151  2017-10-22   POS_04_08   0.00
152  2017-10-22   POS_08_12   0.00
153  2017-10-22   POS_12_16   0.00
154  2017-10-22   POS_16_20   0.00
155  2017-10-22   POS_20_24   0.00
156  2017-10-23   NEG_00_04  10.46
157  2017-10-23   NEG_04_08   9.73
158  2017-10-23   NEG_08_12   0.87
159  2017-10-23   NEG_12_16   1.26
160  2017-10-23   NEG_16_20   0.72
161  2017-10-23   NEG_20_24   0.68
162  2017-10-23   POS_00_04   0.00
163  2017-10-23   POS_04_08   0.00
164  2017-10-23   POS_08_12   0.00
165  2017-10-23   POS_12_16   0.00
166  2017-10-23   POS_16_20   0.00
167  2017-10-23   POS_20_24   0.00
```

What I would like to do is actually do the results for all the products and after organizing in a date frame which I would like to such as

Days as the index and every column as a different product. Due to all the products have the same days and the result would be a array with the ['Results']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can set the date index as :

```
indexed_df = orig_df.set_index('datum_von')
```

You can use a add a column which would be a label encoded version of your products.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
indexed_df['label_products'] = le.fit_transform(indexed['produktname'])
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
onehotmatrix = ohe.fit_transform(indexed_df['label_products'])
# Just join the onehotmatrix on your dataframe
```

You'll have your products encoded as numbers and even as one hot switches, for every product there will be a 1 and other 11 columns would be a 0.

Comment: I suppose could work but No module named sklearn.preprocessing. Can happen because I use an online platform to code then I may not be able to use this library

Comment: You need to install the scikit-learn library to use these modules. Try if you can install it locally and work on your data that way.

Comment: So I did like this but I am not sure if I ended up creating a data frame but looks like one.                                                                                                                                                                                                                          **indexed_df = waps_df1['datum_von']
columns = [Products]
df_ = pd.DataFrame(index = indexed_df, columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs**

Comment: Are you satisfied with the solution or not?

Comment: Now, I have to figure out how to fill it with an array in each cells meaning results. What do you think about the way I did?

Comment: What is [Products]? Essentially you have to pd.merge on the original dataframe and the matrix that you get from one hot encoder. There should be no reason for you to get NaN values.

Comment: Is a list of unique products which I created to be my columns of my date frame. the **Products = waps_df1['produktname'].unique()**  Yeah, the point was creating the data frame with this format but I need to fill every 0 cell with an array of results.

Comment: The way I have mentioned won't need you do make these workarounds. You'll have a proper dataframe with results in place, a column with products labelled as numbers, 12 columns in which every row would have a 1 for the product and 0 for all other products, plus your original product names. You can even drop the label encoded column if you like.